# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading "useRef")

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on a React project, and everything works fine. Then I started using `react-router-dom`, but the router is not working. I want to go to homescreen but it gives me these errors instead:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading "useRef")
```

[image]

app.js:

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Header from './components/header';
import './index.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import HomeScreen from './screens/homeScreen';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header/>
      <main className='py-3'>
        <Container >
        <Route path="/" exact component={HomeScreen} />
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer/>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

HomeScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import products from '../products'
import {Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Product from '../components/product'

function homeScreen() {
  return (

    <div>
       <h1>Latest Products</h1>
        <Row>
            {products.map(product =>(
                <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                  <Product product={product} />
                </Col>
            ))}
        </Row>
     
            
    </div>
  )
}

export default homeScreen
```

Comment: make. sure react-router-dom installed and present in package.json for the project

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, look inside your `package.json` file to make sure every used library is listed either as `"dependencies"` or `devDependencies`. If not, install them individually.

In your case, if you are not seeing `react-router-dom`, open a terminal in the root folder of your project where `package.json` is, and run:

```
npm install react-hook-form
```

If the issue persists, make sure your Node.js version is not superior to the last [recommended](https://nodejs.org/en/) one. If not, downgrade it, and for that, you could use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package from `npm`:

```bash
# if one of the commands does not pass, you may need to use sudo
npm i -g n
n stable
# delete node_modules and start over
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Finally, ensure all your components start with a capital letter, `HomeScreen` and not `homeScreen`. And change the `component` property of `Route` to `element` if you are using the version `6` of React Router Dom:

```js
<Route path="/" exact element={<HomeScreen/>} />
```

Answer (score 1):

i suggest trying this... first, update your `react-router-dom` to latest version.

then import routes like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

now insert the routes component like this:

```
<Container>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" exact element={<HomeScreen />} />
  </Routes>
</Container>
```

> A `<Route>` is only ever to be used as the child of `<Routes>` element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your `<Route>` in a `<Routes>`.

Answer (score 1):

In my Case i Download npm react-router-dom outside my project mean i can't use  cd Prject_name that's why this problem is occured first go to your project cd projecta_name than download npm react-router-dom may be your problem will be solved
also try
npm i react-router-dom@latest

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Update your `react-router-dom` to a recent version that will solve the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading "useRef")".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).