# React, getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading "useRef") at BrowserRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a react project with react-router-dom. I am unable to progress due to an error I can't seem to figure out. The code compiles without error on the terminal, however, the page is entirely blank and Chrome console displays this:

React error page

[image: 1]

here is my code: I followed the official react-router-dom documentation.

```
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import Tickets from './pages/Tickets';
import Nav from './components/Nav';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Nav/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={< Dashboard/>} />
          <Route path="ticket" element={<Tickets />} />
          <Route path="ticket/:id" element={<Tickets editMode={true}/>} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React, getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading "useRef") while using React Router Dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72383919/react-getting-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-user)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error.The problem was that I had installed the react-router-dom outside the folder in which my app is located. As such, the browser router was not being accessed. So, navigate to the folder in which your react app is located then reinstall the react router. This worked for me. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have probably used a hook in a wrong part in your code. Hooks can only be called inside function components before returning the jsx. Or problem might be in `element={<Tickets editMode={true}/>}`

Answer (score 0):

**Do**

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

in the terminal in your project directory.