# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I have created a react app using create-react-app and added my very first component Header. It worked fine. When I start to add Navbar (from react-bootstrap) to my header, compilation was successful but I am getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')' at dev console.[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBgqq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQB2w.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYV9n.png)

Couldn't understand the issue.

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/72383961/7785337

Comment: Thank you! I was missing react-bootstrap library and i installed it is working