# React18 throws invalid hooks error and BrowserRouter error while using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using React v18 and installed few packages react-router-dom react-social-login

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import Home from './container/Home';
import Login from './components/Login';

import { Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
 
const App = () => {
        return(  
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />                    
                </Routes>
        );
}

export default App;
```

Login.js

```js
import React from 'react'

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Home.js

```js
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXb2u.png) I got this error while running the following program. The output Home and Login is not returned.
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLwgW.png)

Index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import  App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: What version of React Router do you have installed?

Comment: @Andy "react": "^18.2.0",
                  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",

Comment: @billyb Andy asked about `react-router-dom`

Comment: @Andy  sorry my bad "react-router-dom": "^6.6.1"

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72383919/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-useref). What version of node are you using?

Comment: @Andy I deleted the node modules and run npm install command again. its working now