# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ref') in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the below error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ref') in React and I used the .jsx extension. I'm learning the react now so could you please help to sort out this issue.

My entire page design logic

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import MaeLogo from '../../../assets/img/maelogo.png';
import EditIcon from '../../../assets/img/editicon.png';

import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';

import { Box, Typography, Link } from '@mui/material';


import {TextField,Button} from "@mui/material";

const mblnmbr = "8341061111";

export default function SignUp(params) {

    //otp validation
    const otpFields = useRef([]);
    const [otp, setOtp] = useState(['', '', '', '', '', '']);
    const [validationErrorOTP, setValidationErrorOTP] = useState('');

    //name validation
    const textInputName = useRef(null);
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [validationErrorName, setValidationErrorName] = useState('');

    //email validation
    const textInputEmail = useRef(null);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [validationErrorEmail, setValidationErrorEmail] = useState('');
    const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);

    //set password validation
    const textInputSetPassword = useRef(null);
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [validationErrorPswd, setValidationerrorPswd] = useState('');

    //Tooltip Error Msg Show
    const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(false);


    //allow char only validation
    const handleInputChangeName = (event) => {
        const newName = event.target.value;

        // Check if the new value matches the character pattern (only letters)
        if (/^[A-Za-z]*$/.test(newName) || newName === '') {
            //alert(newName);
            setName(newName);
        }
    };

    //allow email only validation
    const validateEmail = (input) => {
        // Regular expression to validate email
        const emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
        return emailRegex.test(input);
    };
    const handleInputChangeEmail = (event) => {
        const inputValue = event.target.value;
        setEmail(inputValue);
        setIsValid(validateEmail(inputValue));
    };


    function handle(params) {

        //alert(name);

        if (name === '') {
            setValidationErrorName('Please Enter Name');
            textInputName.current.focus();
            setShowTooltip(true);
        }
        else if (email === '') {
            setValidationErrorEmail('Please Enter Email');
            setValidationErrorName('');
            setEmail('');
            textInputEmail.current.focus();
            setShowTooltip(true);
        }
        else if(!isValid)
        {
            setValidationErrorEmail('Please Enter a valid E-mail Address');
            setValidationErrorName('');
            setEmail('');
            textInputEmail.current.focus();
            setShowTooltip(true);
        }
        else if (!/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$/.test(password)) {
            setValidationerrorPswd('Password must be of minimum 8 characters with at least one digit and one alphabet!');
            setValidationErrorEmail('');
            setPassword('');
            textInputSetPassword.current.focus();
            setShowTooltip(true);
        }


    }



    //button click otp validation
    const handleOtpChange = (index, value) => {

        if (value === '' || /^\d+$/.test(value)) {
            const newOtp = [...otp];
            newOtp[index] = value;
            setOtp(newOtp);
            setShowTooltip(false);

            if (value !== '' && index < otpFields.current.length - 1) {
                otpFields.current[index + 1].focus();
            } else if (value === '' && index > 0) {
                otpFields.current[index - 1].focus();
            }
        }

    };

    const handleButtonClick = () => {

        //const isOtpValid = otp.every(value => /^\d+$/.test(value) && value.length === 1);

        const isOtpValid = otp.every((value, index) => {

            const isValid = /^\d+$/.test(value) && value.length === 1;
            if (!isValid) {
                otpFields.current[index].focus();
            }

            return isValid;

        });

        if (isOtpValid) {

            setValidationErrorOTP('');
            setShowTooltip(false);
            handle();

        } else {

            setValidationErrorOTP('Please Enter OTP');
            setValidationerrorPswd('');
            setValidationErrorName('');
            setValidationErrorEmail('');
            setShowTooltip(true);
        }
    };


    return (

        //<Grid item xs={12}>
            <Box sx={{ p: "50px" }}>
                <Link href="/">
                    <img src={MaeLogo} alt="MAE Log"></img>
                </Link>
                <Box sx={{ pt: "26px", color: "#5DBE52" }}>
                    <Typography>
                        {mblnmbr}
                        <Link sx={{ pl: "19px" }} href="/">
                            <img src={EditIcon} alt="Edit"></img>
                        </Link>
                    </Typography>
                </Box>

                <Box sx={{ pt: "26px", display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>

                    <Typography sx={{ fontSize: "14px", pb: "9px" }}>
                        Enter OTP
                    </Typography>

                </Box>

                <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>

                    <Tooltip open={showTooltip}  title={validationErrorOTP} arrow placement="top-start"></Tooltip>
                    {otp.map((digit, index) => (

                        <TextField
                            style={{ border: "none" }}
                            key={index}
                            ref={el => otpFields.current[index] = el}
                            type="text"
                            maxLength={1}
                            value={digit}
                            onChange={e => handleOtpChange(index, e.target.value)}
                        />

                    ))}
                </Box>

                <Box sx={{ textAlign: "right", pt: "10px" }}>
                    <Link href="/" underline="none">
                        <Typography sx={{ fontSize: "12px", color: "#999999" }}>
                            Resend OTP
                        </Typography>
                    </Link>
                </Box>

                <Box sx={{ pt: "32px" }}>
                    <Typography sx={{ fontSize: "14px", pb: "7px" }}>
                        Name
                    </Typography>
                    <Tooltip open={showTooltip} title={validationErrorName} arrow placement="top">
                        <TextField id="txtsignupname" autoComplete="off" variant="outlined" sx={{ "& fieldset": { border: "none" } }}
                            value={name} onChange={handleInputChangeName} inputRef={textInputName}
                            pattern="[A-Za-z]*"></TextField>
                    </Tooltip>
                </Box>

                <Box sx={{ pt: "7px" }}>
                    <Typography sx={{ fontSize: "14px", pb: "7px" }}>
                        Email
                    </Typography>
                    <Tooltip open={showTooltip} title={validationErrorEmail} arrow placement="top">
                        <TextField id="txtsignupemail" autoComplete="off" variant="outlined" sx={{ "& fieldset": { border: "none" } }}
                            value={email} inputRef={textInputEmail} onChange={handleInputChangeEmail} type="email"></TextField>
                    </Tooltip>
                </Box>

                <Box sx={{ pt: "13px" }}>
                    <Typography sx={{ fontSize: "14px", pb: "4px" }}>
                        Set Password
                    </Typography>
                    <Tooltip open={showTooltip} title={validationErrorPswd} arrow placement="top-start"></Tooltip>
                    <TextField id="txtsignupsetpswd" autoComplete="off" variant="outlined" sx={{ "& fieldset": { border: "none" } }}
                        value={password} onChange={(e) => { setPassword(e.target.value) }} inputRef={textInputSetPassword}
                        type="password"></TextField>
                </Box>

                <Box sx={{ pt: "11px", textAlign: "right" }}>
                    <Button onClick={handleButtonClick} id="btnsignupcontinue" variant="contained">Continue</Button>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        //</Grid>

    );

}
```

Showing error in console

[image: Console error]

Suggest me where I did the mistake and how to resolve this issue.

Comment: where is your Tooltip.js ?

Comment: I'm not using `Tooltip.js `  I'm using only material ui tooltip `import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip'`

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/q/72383919/15288641?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Tooltip requires an element as a child that forwards the ref like the following:**

```
<Tooltip title="Foo">
  <span>Bar</span>
</Tooltip>
```

But two of your `Tooltip`s have no child:

```
<Tooltip open={showTooltip}  
title={validationErrorOTP} 
arrow placement="top-start"></Tooltip>
```

and

```
<Tooltip open={showTooltip} 
title={validationErrorPswd} 
arrow placement="top-start"></Tooltip>
```

Here I have added two empty divs into the `Tooltip`s of `validationErrorOTP` and `validationErrorPswd` since they had missing child.

##### See the following example:

```
    import React, {
      useState,
      useRef
    } from "react";
    import MaeLogo from '../../../assets/img/maelogo.png';
    import EditIcon from '../../../assets/img/editicon.png';

    import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';

    import {
      Box,
      Typography,
      Link
    } from '@mui/material';


    import {
      TextField,
      Button
    } from "@mui/material";

    const mblnmbr = "8341061111";


    export default function SignUp(params) {
      //otp validation
      const otpFields = useRef([]);
      const [otp, setOtp] = useState(["", "", "", "", "", ""]);
      const [validationErrorOTP, setValidationErrorOTP] = useState("");

      //name validation
      const textInputName = useRef(null);
      const [name, setName] = useState("");
      const [validationErrorName, setValidationErrorName] = useState("");

      //email validation
      const textInputEmail = useRef(null);
      const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
      const [validationErrorEmail, setValidationErrorEmail] = useState("");
      const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);

      //set password validation
      const textInputSetPassword = useRef(null);
      const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
      const [validationErrorPswd, setValidationerrorPswd] = useState("");

      //Tooltip Error Msg Show
      const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(false);

      //allow char only validation
      const handleInputChangeName = (event) => {
        const newName = event.target.value;

        // Check if the new value matches the character pattern (only letters)
        if (/^[A-Za-z]*$/.test(newName) || newName === "") {
          //alert(newName);
          setName(newName);
        }
      };

      //allow email only validation
      const validateEmail = (input) => {
        // Regular expression to validate email
        const emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
        return emailRegex.test(input);
      };
      const handleInputChangeEmail = (event) => {
        const inputValue = event.target.value;
        setEmail(inputValue);
        setIsValid(validateEmail(inputValue));
      };

      function handle(params) {
        //alert(name);

        if (name === "") {
          setValidationErrorName("Please Enter Name");
          textInputName.current.focus();
          setShowTooltip(true);
        } else if (email === "") {
          setValidationErrorEmail("Please Enter Email");
          setValidationErrorName("");
          setEmail("");
          textInputEmail.current.focus();
          setShowTooltip(true);
        } else if (!isValid) {
          setValidationErrorEmail("Please Enter a valid E-mail Address");
          setValidationErrorName("");
          setEmail("");
          textInputEmail.current.focus();
          setShowTooltip(true);
        } else if (!/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$/.test(password)) {
          setValidationerrorPswd(
            "Password must be of minimum 8 characters with at least one digit and one alphabet!"
          );
          setValidationErrorEmail("");
          setPassword("");
          textInputSetPassword.current.focus();
          setShowTooltip(true);
        }
      }

      //button click otp validation
      const handleOtpChange = (index, value) => {
        if (value === "" || /^\d+$/.test(value)) {
          const newOtp = [...otp];
          newOtp[index] = value;
          setOtp(newOtp);
          setShowTooltip(false);

          if (value !== "" && index < otpFields.current.length - 1) {
            otpFields.current[index + 1].focus();
          } else if (value === "" && index > 0) {
            otpFields.current[index - 1].focus();
          }
        }
      };

      const handleButtonClick = () => {
        //const isOtpValid = otp.every(value => /^\d+$/.test(value) && value.length === 1);

        const isOtpValid = otp.every((value, index) => {
          const isValid = /^\d+$/.test(value) && value.length === 1;
          if (!isValid) {
            otpFields.current[index].focus();
          }

          return isValid;
        });

        if (isOtpValid) {
          setValidationErrorOTP("");
          setShowTooltip(false);
          handle();
        } else {
          setValidationErrorOTP("Please Enter OTP");
          setValidationerrorPswd("");
          setValidationErrorName("");
          setValidationErrorEmail("");
          setShowTooltip(true);
        }
      };

      return (
        //<Grid item xs={12}>
        <
        Box sx = {
          {
            p: "50px"
          }
        } >
        <
        Link href = "/" >
        <
        img src = {
          MaeLogo
        }
        alt = "MAE Log" > < /img> <
        /Link> <
        Box sx = {
          {
            pt: "26px",
            color: "#5DBE52"
          }
        } >
        <
        Typography > {
          mblnmbr
        } <
        Link sx = {
          {
            pl: "19px"
          }
        }
        href = "/" >
        <
        img src = {
          EditIcon
        }
        alt = "Edit" > < /img> <
        /Link> <
        /Typography> <
        /Box>

        <
        Box sx = {
          {
            pt: "26px",
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "space-between"
          }
        } >
        <
        Typography sx = {
          {
            fontSize: "14px",
            pb: "9px"
          }
        } > Enter OTP < /Typography> <
        /Box>

        <
        Box sx = {
          {
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "space-between"
          }
        } >
        <
        Tooltip open = {
          showTooltip
        }
        title = {
          validationErrorOTP
        }
        arrow placement = "top-start" >
        <
        div > < /div> <
        /Tooltip> {
          otp.map((digit, index) => ( <
            TextField style = {
              {
                border: "none"
              }
            }
            key = {
              index
            }
            ref = {
              (el) => (otpFields.current[index] = el)
            }
            type = "text"
            maxLength = {
              1
            }
            value = {
              digit
            }
            onChange = {
              (e) => handleOtpChange(index, e.target.value)
            }
            />
          ))
        } <
        /Box>

        <
        Box sx = {
          {
            textAlign: "right",
            pt: "10px"
          }
        } >
        <
        Link href = "/"
        underline = "none" >
        <
        Typography sx = {
          {
            fontSize: "12px",
            color: "#999999"
          }
        } >
        Resend OTP <
        /Typography> <
        /Link> <
        /Box>

        <
        Box sx = {
          {
            pt: "32px"
          }
        } >
        <
        Typography sx = {
          {
            fontSize: "14px",
            pb: "7px"
          }
        } > Name < /Typography> <
        Tooltip open = {
          showTooltip
        }
        title = {
          validationErrorName
        }
        arrow placement = "top" >
        <
        TextField id = "txtsignupname"
        autoComplete = "off"
        variant = "outlined"
        sx = {
          {
            "& fieldset": {
              border: "none"
            }
          }
        }
        value = {
          name
        }
        onChange = {
          handleInputChangeName
        }
        inputRef = {
          textInputName
        }
        pattern = "[A-Za-z]*" >
        < /TextField> <
        /Tooltip> <
        /Box>

        <
        Box sx = {
          {
            pt: "7px"
          }
        } >
        <
        Typography sx = {
          {
            fontSize: "14px",
            pb: "7px"
          }
        } > Email < /Typography> <
        Tooltip open = {
          showTooltip
        }
        title = {
          validationErrorEmail
        }
        arrow placement = "top" >
        <
        TextField id = "txtsignupemail"
        autoComplete = "off"
        variant = "outlined"
        sx = {
          {
            "& fieldset": {
              border: "none"
            }
          }
        }
        value = {
          email
        }
        inputRef = {
          textInputEmail
        }
        onChange = {
          handleInputChangeEmail
        }
        type = "email" >
        < /TextField> <
        /Tooltip> <
        /Box>

        <
        Box sx = {
          {
            pt: "13px"
          }
        } >
        <
        Typography sx = {
          {
            fontSize: "14px",
            pb: "4px"
          }
        } >
        Set Password <
        /Typography> <
        Tooltip open = {
          showTooltip
        }
        title = {
          validationErrorPswd
        }
        arrow placement = "top-start" >
        <
        div > < /div> <
        /Tooltip> <
        TextField id = "txtsignupsetpswd"
        autoComplete = "off"
        variant = "outlined"
        sx = {
          {
            "& fieldset": {
              border: "none"
            }
          }
        }
        value = {
          password
        }
        onChange = {
          (e) => {
            setPassword(e.target.value);
          }
        }
        inputRef = {
          textInputSetPassword
        }
        type = "password" >
        < /TextField> <
        /Box>

        <
        Box sx = {
          {
            pt: "11px",
            textAlign: "right"
          }
        } >
        <
        Button onClick = {
          handleButtonClick
        }
        id = "btnsignupcontinue"
        variant = "contained" >
        Continue <
        /Button> <
        /Box> <
        /Box>
        //</Grid>
      );
    }
```

Link to Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-ben-xn3282?file=/src/SIgnUp.js

**Reference:**

[0] https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tooltip/

[1] https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/18119